# Nested dictionary comprehension parity with loop, but still error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to write a nested dictionary comprehension to be functionally equivalent to this:

```
new_dict = {}
for dict_ in x, y:
    for key, value in dict_.items():
        new_dict[key] = value
return new_dict
```

This attempt does not work:

```
return {k: v for k, v in dict_.items() for dict_ in (x, y)}
```

Other than the fact that it's not using the `=` operator, I'm not sure why this isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leftmost loop is executed first. Swap the two `for` loops:

```
{k: v for dict_ in (x, y) for k, v in dict_.items()}
```